# Django NameError: name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a view that filters blog posts by topic, so I added a field in my post form called "topic" and,

I created a view:
And I defined the path in urls.py:

I get this error in Terminal:

```py
class PoliticalPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/political_posts.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(topic=Political).order_by('date_posted')
```

```py
 path('politics/', PoliticalPostListView.as_view(), name='political-posts'),
```

I used a template from a working user_posts.html to test:

```py
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="md-3"> Posts by {{ view.kwargs.username }} ({{ page_obj.paginator.count }})</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{post.author.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ post.topic }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Error:

```py
File "/Users/leaghbranner/Desktop/django_project/blog/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('politics/', PoliticalPostListView.as_view(), name='political-posts'),
NameError: name 'PoliticalPostListView' is not defined
```

And the "This Site Cannot Be Reached." page on my browser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to import PoliticalPostListView in urls.py

Comment: 'PoliticalPostListView' is the view name in the views.py  that u are using.. please check it that the name of the view and the view that you are defined in the url.py are same or not

Answer (score 1):

In your `urls.py`.

if import is used like this:

```py
from . import views

# then use:
path('politics/', views.PoliticalPostListView.as_view(), name='political-posts'),
```

But if using:

```py
from .views import PoliticalPostListView

# then use:
path('politics/', PoliticalPostListView.as_view(), name='political-posts'),
```